# Плагин количество продуктов на каталоге woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Питаюсь реализовать количество продуктов на каталоге, но как то не получается и плагина не получается найти.
Дайте подсказку как реализовать или ссылка на плагин скиньте пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте плагин Woocommerce Products Per Page